# Is there any way to mount android directory from windows/linux programmatically/command-line via LAN?

Tags: java, android, linux, command-line, mount

I know how to mount shared windows folder from android (jcifs) but how to do it vice versa.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the right site to ask this question, but try [jmtpfs](https://github.com/kiorky/jmtpfs). You could try [mtpfs](http://www.adebenham.com/mtpfs/), but it did not work for me out of the box, so I do not suggest it.

Comment: I want to mount via local network. Is it possible sir?

Comment: You could find a ssh daemon for your phone and use sshfs

Comment: I found an app that create ssh server on Android:SSHDroid.
Do you know how to implement a ssh server like this in Java?

Comment: @dadylonglegs, Take a look at http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/

Comment: work fine on Java Desktop, but when I try the same on Android, it rise error: "Could not find a valid sshd io provider".

Comment: @dadylonglegs, You should accept my answer if I've helped you, and ask another question and we'll see if we can't get you mounted.

Comment: Ok sir, but I receive "You have reached your question limit" when trying to ask a new question. You are pointing me to the right approach, thanks.